# why does *ptr++ act like *(ptr++) and not (*ptr)++?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [++ on a dereferenced pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859770/on-a-dereferenced-pointer-in-c)

Similarly, what would
*ptr += 1
*ptr % 8, and
*ptr / 8
be?

The differences seem confusing.
Is this, perhaps, compiler dependent?

Comment: Why is `1 + 2 * 2` 5 and not 6?

Comment: [You may find this helpful.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: funny how everybody managed to find a different link to the "operator precedence" pages.

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with operator precedence. The `*` operator has a lower precedence than `++` so it occurs last.

Here's a Wikipedia chart that lists all the operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

You can see in the chart that postfix `++` has a precedence of 2 while `*` dereference has a precedence of 3. (The numbers are slightly backwards, as lower numbers have higher precedence).

Answer (score 3):

Operator precedence. The `++` operator "binds more tightly" than the `*` operator.

Here's the table, in order of precedence.
http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html

This is not compiler dependent. It will always behave this way.

Answer (score 2):

Because of precedence (that's just how C works).

**[C FAQ on the * exact * subject](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/unopprec2.html)**

> The postfix ++ and -- operators
>   essentially have higher precedence
>   than the prefix unary operators.
>   Therefore, *p++ is equivalent to
>   *(p++);

Answer (score 2):

because of [operator precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence)

the postfix ++ has a higher precedence than the * operator. It's not compiler dependent.

*ptr += 1 will increase the value pointed to by ptr by one (or call the appropriate overloaded operator)
*ptr % 8 will calculate the remainder of the value pointed to by ptr divided by 8
*ptr / 8 will calculate the division of the value pointed to by ptr and 8

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence):

> For the ISO C 1999 standard, section 6.5.6 note 71 states that the C grammar provided by the specification defines the precedence of the C operators

This means that the operator precedence is governed by C standard.

Answer (score 1):

The differences seem confusing. Is this, perhaps, compiler dependent?

No, the precedence of operators is defined in the c lang spec.
And and so *prt++ is always deferencing the pointer before the post-increment occurs.