# Incrementing pointer (ptr++) and (*ptr++)

Tags: c, pointers

I was revisiting pointers when I had this doubt.

```
int *ptr;
int arr[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};
ptr = &arr[0];
```

Now `printf("Value: %d",*ptr);` would print `10`

if I do:

```
ptr++;
printf("Value: %d",*ptr);
```

the result would be: `20`

Similarly if I do:

```
*ptr++;
printf("Value: %d",*ptr);
```

the result is: `30`

But

```
printf("Value: %d",++*ptr);
```

gives me `31`

I thought since `ptr` is of type `int` when I increment it, it would jump 4 bytes to the next memory location. But why does it show the same behavior for `*ptr++` and `ptr++` and not for `++*ptr`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does *ptr++ act like *(ptr++) and not (*ptr)++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271028/why-does-ptr-act-like-ptr-and-not-ptr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet is obvious: it prints what `ptr` points to, i.e. 10.

The second one, moves the pointer forward of one element, which then points to the next element, i.e. 20.

The third snippet is exactly the same as the previous one, because its first instruction increments the pointer and returns the unincremented value, which is dereferenced, but its result is discarded; what is dereferenced in the `printf` is the incremented pointer, which now points to 30.

The last snippet is different: `++*ptr` is `++(*ptr)`; `*ptr` dereferences `ptr` (which already points to `30`), yielding 30, and `++` increments such value, which becomes 31.

Answer (score 8):

Because of *precedence*.

- `*ptr++` is the same as `*(ptr++)`, the pointer is incremented, but its *previous* value is dereferenced.
- `ptr++` is the same as, well, `ptr++`.
- `++*ptr` is the same as `++(*ptr)`, i.e. it increments the thing being pointed to, not the pointer.

Comment: When i do `*(ptr++)` shouldn't it dereference the value of `ptr` and increment it rather than incrementing the pointer to the next memory location? Isn't that what happens with `++(*ptr)`?

Comment: @noMAD: No, because in `*(ptr++)`, the parentheses mean that `++` is applied to `ptr`, not to `*ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `* ptr++`, you are actually doing `* (ptr++)`, so the pointer get incremented, not the variable it points to

When `++ *ptr`, it's actually `++(* ptr)`, so it increments the value returned by the pointer

Answer (score 1):

The order of C Precedence from high priority:

> ()
>   ++
>   * &    *for pointers*
>   * /
>   + -

so,

```
 *ptr++ equivlant to *(ptr++)
 ++*ptr equivlant to ++(*ptr)
```

and for this line *ptr++; it will only increment the ptr pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to this is that whenever both are unary operators, then associativity is from right to left.

*ptr++ --> first increment pointer to next location and then dereference the value at that location.

Similarly *++ptr -->first increment pointer and then dereference.

++*ptr --> first dereference value at ptr and then increment the value.