# pre/post increment pointer

Tags: c

Is there a difference between the two expressions:

```
(*x)++
```

and

```
++(*x)
```

I can see both of these statements replace the contents of (*x+1) in *x. But are there any differences between them?

Comment: Use them with a printf..

Comment: possible duplicate of [++ on a dereferenced pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859770/on-a-dereferenced-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @dirkgently Wrong duplicate (though I guess there is also a real duplicate to this question somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One increments the values stored in `x` *before* it is used (pre), while the other does it *after* it is used (post).

Also note that `++(*x)` is *not* the same as `(*x + 1)`. The first increments the value and stores it back, the other just increments the value.

Comment: @mikefisher Ah, in that case yes it's the same.

Answer (score 7):

`(*x)++` *evaluates* to the value of`*x`; as a *side effect*, the value in `*x` will be incremented by 1.

`++(*x)` *evaluates* to the value of `*x` + 1; as a *side effect*, the value in `*x` will be incremented by 1.

Assuming the code:

```
int a = 5;
int *x = &a;
```

`(*x)++` will evaluate to `5`, while `++(*x)` will evaluate to 6.

Note that the side effect does not have to be applied immediately after the expression has been evaluated; it only needs to be applied before the next sequence point.

Also note that the parentheses *matter* for `(*x)++`; postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*x++` would be parsed as `*(x++)`; it still evaluates to the value of `*x`, but as a side effect advances the *pointer*, rather than increment the thing being pointed *to*.  Prefix `++` and unary `*` have the same precedence, so they're applied left-to-right; thus `++(*x)` and `++*x` would have the same result (`*x` gets incremented, not `x`).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning importance of parentheses.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Let us say the value pointed by x is 10 i:e (*x is 10)

```
y = (*x)++;
```

the above statement will be executed as 
1. y = *x  
2. *x = *x + 1
so y = 10 & *x is 11

```
y = ++(*x);
```

the above statement will be executed as 
1. *x = *x + 1
2. y = *x  
so y = 11 & *x is 11

Answer (score 1):

One is "pre" and the other is "post". That's the difference. One is evaluated before the the increment (the first option), the other is evaluated after the increment (the second option).