# Pointers in Arduino, not updating outside variable

Tags: pointers, arduino

Not sure what I'm doing wrong because aValue and bValue aren't being updated.

```
int aValue;
int bValue;

void setup() {
    aValue = 0;
    bValue = 0;
}

void loop() {
    someFunc(&aValue, &bValue);
    // code for printing aValue and bValue
}

void someFunc(int *a, int *b) {
    *a++;
    *b++;
}
```

Comment: You are incrementing the pointers; not the values that they point to. Use `(*a)++;` or `*a +=1;` instead.

Comment: I just saw your post wildlasser. Thank you too! Someone helped me earlier with that syntax :)

Comment: You are wrong. I was earlier. Never mind.

Comment: Your post was really earlier than mine. I was just saying that I didn't see it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that pointers and post-increment does not do what you want.

If you write

```
void someFunc(int *a, int *b) {
    *a = *a+1;
    *b = *b+1;
}
```

it works

See 
[++ on a dereferenced pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859770/on-a-dereferenced-pointer-in-c)
for an explanation of why `*a++` increments the pointer itself.

Comment: I got it working too by using (*a)++; Thanks for the help too and I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

The variables a and b in someFunc are copies and you are incrementing the copy.
Precedence order for post increment is higher then the pointer de-reference so you are incrementing the copies of your pointers. The de-reference has no effect.

When in doubt use parentheses.

```
void someFunc(int *a, int *b) 
{
    (*a)++;
    (*b)++;
}
```

although some people say you shoud do

```
void someFunc(int *a, int *b) 
{
    ++(*a);
    ++(*b);
}
```

Since post increment technically returns a value while pre increment just increments. In this case most compilers would produce the same code. I have never looked at the AVR compiler.