# C Pointers and Arrays with static decleration

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static

Working on some pointer related things in C.I'm wondering what the third line is doing?

```
char *return_pointer;
static char string_buffer[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
return_pointer = &string_buffer[sizeof(string_buffer)-1]; 
*return_pointer = '\0';
```

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in that line?

Comment: It seems to be used to terminate the string at the last char in the buffer.

Comment: Maybe `return_pointer` is needed for something else later, but as the code snippet stands, the last two lines could be accomplished by: `string_buffer[sizeof(string_buffer)-1] = '\0';`. Maybe that helps clarify. In either case, they're making sure that the last byte of the buffer is a NULL (`'\0'`).

Comment: Could also be there for readability I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```
return_pointer = &string_buffer[sizeof(string_buffer)-1];
```

is assigning the address of last element of `string_buffer` to `return_pointer`.
The statement

```
*return_pointer = '\0';
```

is simply terminating the `string_buffer` with null character.

Comment: additionally if i use 
     *--ptr_return=*message++;
am I incrementing the address then using the pointer.

Comment: You need to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859770/on-a-dereferenced-pointer-in-c?lq=1_).