# Pointers arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I did a recursion exercise and I could not understand what is the difference between doing `*p++` or `*p+=1.`

Both of them should add 1 to the value pointed at but for some reason `*p+=1` works and `*p++` doesn't.

```
void rec(char a[], int *p ,int i)
{
    if(a[i+1]== '\0')
        return;

    if(a[i]==a[i+1])
        *p+=1;

    rec(a, p, i+1);
}


void rec(char a[], int *p ,int i)
{
    if(a[i+1]== '\0')
        return;

    if(a[i]==a[i+1])
        *p++;

    rec(a, p, i+1);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-increment on a dereferenced pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859770/post-increment-on-a-dereferenced-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

`*p += 1;` means, dereference the pointer `p` and then increment the dereferenced value by `1`. While `*p++;` means

```
*p;
p += 1; // Increment the pointer itself
```

This is because `++` has higher precedence than `*` operator so compiler will parse it as `*(p++);`.

`(*p)++` is equivalent to `*p += 1;`.

Comment: And `*p += 1` means `(*p) += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence wise

```
++ > * > +=
```

Here `*p+=1` is increasing the value that is pointed by `p`. Here the value at the memory location pointed by `p` is incremented. You can see the change in your code.

In the second case, `*p++` it is just increasing the pointer `p` and then it de-references the value but you don't assign that r-value anywhere. This is not changing the actual content that there is in the memory pointed by `p`.

That is why in second case you don't see any change in the working variables and concluded that it doesn't work which is certainly not the case.